# Insights from non-dimensionalization

Tags: fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, differential-equations

I have this partial differential equation which models the diffusion of a contaminant substance in a 1-dimensional river. The terms represent the following:

- The first term represents the diffusion effect with the diffusion constant $D$
- The second term represents the convection effect with a flow rate $v$
- The third term represents the decay effect with a decay rate $\alpha$.

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} 
  = D\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} 
    - v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
    - \alpha u
  \qquad (5.33)
$$

- $u$ is the amount of contaminant substance, at time $t$, and distance $x$ from the source.

The author then non-dimensionalized the equation and comes to the following result:

$$
\frac{\partial \hat u}{\partial \hat t} 
  = \hat D\frac{\partial^2 \hat u}{\partial \hat x^2} 
    - \frac{\partial \hat u}{\partial \hat x} - \hat u
  \qquad (5.35)
$$

with $\hat D = \dfrac {\alpha D}{v^2}$.

In the nondimensionalized form the author states, the following:

> Because there is only one parameter left ($\hat D$) it can be used to conclude whether the diffusion effect dominates the whole system:
> if $D \gg 1$ it dominates and if $D \ll 1$ it is negligible.

**My question is, why can one conclude that?**

My assumption is, that $\hat D$ acts like a scaling factor and since the second and third term have no such factor they are scaled to 1.

**But why can't one make such conclusion with the original equation too?**
If $D > v$ and $D > \alpha$ wouldn’t I get the same insights?

Comment: Inequalities like $D>\alpha$ is undefined since $D$ and $\alpha$ don't have the same dimension. So, in any case, you must compare quantities with the same dimension.

Comment: @Miyase Totally missed that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare homogeneous quantities, as suggested by Miyase in the comment section. And to get homogeneous quantities, you need non-dimensional numbers produced by the non-dimensionalization process.

It looks like there are some extra assumptions in the non-dimensionalization process. Let's do it step by step, writing all the physical quantities as the product of a reference dimensional value and the non-dimensional value
\begin{equation}
  u = U \tilde{u} \ , \ \ x = L \tilde{x} \ , \ \ t = T \tilde{t} \ ,
\end{equation}
and taking equal to 1 the non dimensional values of the constants, so that these physical quantities coincide with the reference dimensional value,
\begin{equation}
  v = V \ , \ \ \alpha = \alpha \ , \ \ D = D \ . 
\end{equation}
Putting these expressions in the original dimensional equation, we get
\begin{equation}
 \dfrac{U}{T}\dfrac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{t}} = \dfrac{D U}{L^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{x}^2} - \dfrac{V U}{L} \dfrac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{x}} - \alpha U \tilde{u} \ .
\end{equation}
Let's multiply both sides by $T/U$, to get
\begin{equation}
 \dfrac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{t}} = \dfrac{D T}{L^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{x}^2} - \dfrac{V T}{L} \dfrac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{x}} - \alpha T \tilde{u} \ .
\end{equation}
As you can see, in general there should be 3 non-dimensional number of the problem. Now, it's possible to reduce these numbers if there are no independent scales for some of the physical quantities involved in the problem. As an example, from what I can see from your result, there is no independent time scale and length scale, and thus it's possible to define them as
\begin{equation}
  T = \dfrac{1}{\alpha} \ , \ \ L = V T = \dfrac{V}{\alpha} \ .
\end{equation}
Only with this choice of the time and length scales, you get the non-dimensional equation in the form written in your question with only one relevant non-dimensional number,
\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{D T}{L^2} = D \dfrac{1}{\alpha} \dfrac{\alpha^2}{V^2} = \dfrac{D \alpha}{V^2} \ ,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 \dfrac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{t}} = \dfrac{D \alpha}{V^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{x}^2} - \dfrac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{x}} - \tilde{u} \ .
\end{equation}

From the whole procedure, you should realize that the non-dimensionalization process could be tricky. I'd suggest to always perform non-dimensionalization before asserting that some terms is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: So based on your answer would you also conclude, that if D^ >> 1 the diffusion effect dominates the system, because D^ acts like a scaling parameter?

Comment: More or less, yes. But this reduce your problem to a stationary problem. But in order to choose the prevailing physical process, I'd focus on the non dimensional version of the equation that you can find in the answer where there is the time derivative non the left hand side and three terms multiplied by three different non-dimensional numbers. This way, you could have a time-dependent problem with the relevant physical phenomena. Anyway, the answer may depend on the domain of the problem as well.

Comment: Is there any time scale prescribed? If not, take it as $1/\alpha$. Is there any length scale (any characteristic size of physical domain)? If yes, and if there is a velocity scale $V$ (some prescribed velocity), you should avoid setting $L = VT$ and use those quantities to get the value of the non-dimensional parameter weighting the convection, and so on